# Try catch for range and alpha errors in java

Tags: java, exception

This method adds an integer to an array. I have to figure out how to do a try catch for the input to catch negative integers and things like letters, and i can't figure out how to do it. How would i do this?

```
private static int[] addInt (int[] ara, Scanner kb) {
   int[] newAra = new int[ara.length + 1];
   for(int i = 0; i < ara.length; i++) {
      newAra[i] = ara[i];
      }
   System.out.println("Enter new integer:");
   newAra[newAra.length-1] = kb.nextInt();
   selectionSort(newAra);
   return newAra;
   }
```

Comment: If performance is even a lil bit of concern... Use arraylist instead of discarding an array, creating new one evertime and filling it with the previous values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` does support negative numbers. If you want to have an exception for negative numbers, you have to generate it yourself. Your code will only throw a `InputMismatchException` from the `Scanner` class which will being thrown up if the next token in the scanner doesn't match with the regular expression for integer, with other words; at characters.

Here below is an example of throwing an exception for negative numbers for your method

```
int value = kb.nextInt();
if (value < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
else newAra[newAra.length-1] = kb.nextInt();
```

and in your code,

```
try {
    my_int_array = addInt(my_int_array, scanner);
}
catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
     // tell that it's not a digit - number
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
     // tell that it's a negative input
}
catch (Exception e) {
     // to catch all other exceptions from the Scanner class like IllegalStateException ...
}
```

Comment: "By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1"

Comment: it keeps telling me that class NegativeNumberException does not exist.

Comment: This works for negative input, but if the input is a letter, the program bombs.

Comment: if you check the [documentation - Scanner.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) you can see that it would throw an `InputMismatchException` when using a non-digit input. Can you add which error (or explain better) would cause the 'program bombing' issue ?